# Ajax is not work properly?

Tags: php, ajax, phalcon

I am getting `dataArray` to insertAction and sending mysql function where I am inserting data to table. When uri is `domain.com/v2/translate` it's working but when uri is `domain.com/v2/translate/lid/2` for example, than Phalcon is causing about routes! And I have this routes define .

```
 $('.save').click(function(e){

    var langKeyId = $(this).prev('input').attr('id');
    var translateText = $(this).prev('input').val();
    var lid = $(this).prev('input').attr('data-lid');
    var dataArray = [langKeyId, translateText, lid];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "translate/insert",
        data: {dataArray : dataArray},
        success: function(r) {
            $(this).disabled = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: do not use the backticks around the variable name `langKeyId`

Comment: @RamRaider i don't use backticks in code, improperly copying this into.

Comment: You are using a relative path: `url: "translate/insert"` so that will only work on pages where the relative path resolves to the correct route. Using an absolute path would solve that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

`url: "translate/insert"`

use

`url: "/translate/insert"`

or an absolute path like `url: "http://domain.com/v2/translate/insert"`

If you use the URL without the leading '/' you are actually doing an ajax call to `domain.com/v2/translate/lid/2/translate/insert`.